# Cannot push to github at any repository

Tags: git, github

It is very strange, but I cannot commit any repository (and new ones) to github.
I have uploaded my ssh-key to github.

```
demas@demas-home:~/dotfiles$ ssh -T git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.130' to the list of known hosts.
```

Hi demas! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Now I create a new repository and try to push the first commit to github:

```
touch README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/demas/netrunner.git
git push -u origin master
```

But github asks my username and password. Why ?

And even I put my username and password I will get the error:

```
demas@demas-home:~/netrunner$ git push -u origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': demas
Password for 'https://demas@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/demas/netrunner.git/'
```

I use two-factor authentification if it matters.

Comment: did you enter your 2fa code for the password? see toward the bottom of https://help.github.com/articles/providing-your-2fa-security-code

Comment: thanks. it helps me. i need to enter personal access token (https://github.com/settings/applications) as password. or i can use ssh url instead https

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is in this line

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/demas/netrunner.git
```

git doesn't use your ssh keys when tries to access server via http protocol (Basic http auth is used in this case as far as i know ). Use ssh access (url looks like git@github.com:username/reponame.git)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to fix this would be to use the ssh url to clone your git repo 
into a new directory and work there.

Comment: nonsense. GitHub HTTPS is read and write if you have push permission for the repo. The problem was that a) OP was using 2fa so he needs to enter a token instead of a password and b) he wanted to use SSH but was using an HTTPS url